# I am getting these Errors from users, I have implemented AnimationDrawablein my app

Tags: android

I am using AnimationDrawable with 9 images on background to `swi`

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/france" android:duration="3000" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/australia" android:duration="3000" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/america" android:duration="3000" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/asia" android:duration="3000" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/egypt" android:duration="3000" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/germany" android:duration="3000" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/turkey" android:duration="3000" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/pakistan" android:duration="3000" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/dubai" android:duration="3000" />

layout.setBackgroundDrawable(getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.spin_animation));
AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) layout.getBackground();
```

Its working Fine on All my devices at my company I have around 5 devices: nexus 5 samsung j7 etc. But as my apps is very famous with millions of downloads i am having this issue my images are of Average size of 100kb[image: this is the logcat 1]
[image: this is 2nd]
[image: these are 2 errors]

Comment: You may need to compress the size of images which are named countries

Comment: can you send piece of code in which you are getting crash?